# Code change to an existing store in Magento2

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, language

I changed the code of an existing store view from "at" to "es" and just activated it.
I have already entered the translation file for Spanish ---> es_ES.csv.
When I try to enter inside the store I changed I see that the paths are wrong. I see that it still gets me:
"static/version7483565482/frontend/vendor/Magento/de_AT/css/styles-l.min.css"
The path that should get me is:
"static/version7483565482/frontend/vendor/Magento/es_ES/css/styles-l.min.css".

Also, the translation file es_ES.csv inside i18n folder does not work and does not take the translation.

Note: I am currently in production mode with my site.

How can i do?

Comment: You also need to change locale from admin